# Relative Layout Android put one image on top of another

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I want the image that I use as a button to appear above the large image but I don't know how to do it. Could you help me?

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/details_nombre_ofi"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/flecha" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/details_imagen_of"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </ImageView>
```

[here is the image, I want the square to be seen above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2az9.png)

Comment: You have A `RelativeLayout` but it seems you are trying to use stuff from `ConstraintLayout` that does not work like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "i'm just change Relative to Linear and make orientation vertical. that what you want i think"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Button"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="220dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

> "copie and paste this code on your xml"
>   "note : if you want use Relative layout add `android:layout_above=""` to ImageView or Button "

Answer (score 0):

You can use of this property in your XML file:

```
android:layout_above="@+id/YOUR_VIEW_ID"
```